# DateDiff function in SSRS (report server) gives error?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Im trying to find the days gap between two dates using DateDiff function.
I have 2 datasets defined. If `companycode` is 'AB' then from one dataset else from another dataset I retrieve data.

Here is my expression. When I change to preview mode, it shows redmark  to the first  `First(Fields!PeriodFrom.Value` line. Why? (after generating report that field shows `#Error`

What Im doing wrong here?

```
 =IIF(Parameters!CompanyCode.Value="AB", 
    DateDiff("d",First(Fields!PeriodFrom.Value, "ABReportData"), First(Fields!PeriodTo.Value, "ABReportData")),
    DateDiff("d",First(Fields!PeriodFrom.Value, "XYReportData"), First(Fields!PeriodTo.Value, "XYReportData")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two possible scenarios. First one is the expression

```
=First(Fields!PeriodFrom.Value, "ABReportData")
```

doesnt return a value. Add a column with this expression and check if you get a value.

If the value is correct, make sure that the `DateDiff()` function gets a date:

```
=IIF(Parameters!CompanyCode.Value="AB", 
     DateDiff("d",
              CDate(First(Fields!PeriodFrom.Value, "ABReportData")), 
              CDate(First(Fields!PeriodTo.Value, "ABReportData"))
              ),
     DateDiff("d",
              CDate(First(Fields!PeriodFrom.Value, "XYReportData")), 
              CDate(First(Fields!PeriodTo.Value, "XYReportData"))
              )
     )
```

Comment: The issue was the date format. I passed  like '01-08-2019' . But function works for '2019-08-01' format

Comment: Yep, I thought something like that. And `CDate()` solves in most of the cases the problem.